# xpath() returns empty list

Tags: python, xpath, terminal, scrapy

xpath returns empty list python scrapy terminal.
HTML code is below

```
<div class="productDisplay productDisplay925670 nodeMembercopy_466 nodeMember466 nodeMember465 nodeMemberb_TRITON "data-path="">
```

terminal code is:

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="productDisplay"]')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "productDisplay")]')` or use `response.css(".productDisplay")`

Comment: Thankyou, the answer worked. What was wrong in my code? is it because I didnot use the full class name?

Comment: Yep, when you use xpath, your equation for class is strict. So order of your classes, additional spaces, etc can affect the result.

Comment: Thankyou for info

Answer (score 1):

in your xpath:

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="productDisplay"]')
```

you mention `=` sign to compare class which strictly compare class to be exact `productDisplay` While there are other classes too.

So, if you are sure of one class but there are other classes too you can use `contains` attribute in xpath as:

```
xpath = '//*[contains(@class, "productDisplay")]'    #This way it will search all elements having at least this class.
```